# WSO2 hosted Feature Repository HTTPS

Tags: wso2

Are there any hosted wso2 feature repositories that use https? I tired adding  https to product-dist.wso2.com/p2/carbon/releases/wilkes/ just to see if it would work but it doesn't look like anything is using the standard 443 port. I could not find anything thing searching the internet.

It would be nice be able to validate the servers we are connecting to when loading features from WSO2 and not worry about a MITM supplying a malicious code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no feature repositories hosted with 'https' from WSO2.

The official WSO2 Carbon features are only available in Equinox P2 repository at: http://dist.wso2.org/p2/carbon/releases.